# How can I make a word as variable in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, variables

I am trying to learn C and I'm making a very simple program which will ask for your name and then displays it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char name[30];    
    printf("\n\tWhat is your name?:");    
    scanf("%c",&name);    
    printf("\n\tHi,%c.n\n",name);    
}
```

After I compile it and try to type a name it just gives a random letter as the output of `printf`.

Comment: `"%c"` is the format specifier for a character. Use `"%s"`.

Comment: Are you getting warning messages while compiling your code? They are there for some reason.... don't ignore them.

Comment: That worked thanks. I thought "%s" was for "string" so i did not try it. It wasn't giving any warnings when compiling though.

Comment: If you didn't get any warnings from your compiler, you need to find out how to make it give you helpful (necessary) warnings — or get a better compiler.  For example, using GCC (GNU C Compiler from the GNU Compiler Collection), you should compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11 -O3 -g …` or thereabouts, and because of `-Werror`, you won't be able to run the code until it compiles with no warnings.

Comment: Yes, "%s" is for string, i.e., a sequence of characters. That's what a name is.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their answers, they all teach me a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. Let's look:

```
main()
{
```

You should really declare the return type for `main`, which is traditionally `int`.

```
char name[30];
printf("\n\tWhat is your name?:");
```

No real problem here, except that you're setting yourself up for a classic buffer overrun. If someone types more than 30 characters into your program, your program will write data in places it shouldn't. That's a classic security blunder. It's no big deal here in this toy app, but it's important to know about

```
scanf("%c",&name);
```

You're using `%c` here as the format specifier. That probably makes sense since the data type looks like `char`, but in fact it's `char[]`, i.e. an array of characters. Use `$s` instead to collect a whole string. Also, you really don't need the `&` before `name`... `name` contains the starting address of the array, and `&name` means the same thing.

```
printf("\n\tHi,%c.n\n",name);
```

Same problem here: use `%s` again.

Here's a version that works:

```
int main(void)
{
    char name[30];
    printf("\n\tWhat is your name?:");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\n\tHi,%s\n",name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
char name[30];
```

`name` is character buffer of `30` characters i.e you can store max `29` characters as user name and `1` byte you need to reserve for `\0` characters.
And here

```
scanf("%c",&name); /* %c is for scanning single character */
```

since `name` is char array and to scan character buffer at run-time use `%s` format specifier. For e.g

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

And while printing `name` use `%s` instead of `%c`. For e.g

```
printf("\n\tHi,%s.n\n",name);
```

Side note, always compile with minimal warning flags like `-Wall`. For e.g

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror test.c
```

Also your version of `main()` is not correct as standard says

> **5.1.2.2.1  Program  startup**  It  shall  be  defined  with  a  return  type  of **int** and  **with  no parameters**:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> or  with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*...*/ }
> ```

For e.g

```
int main(void) /* No argument i.e void */
{
    char name[30] = {}; /* initialize the char buffer */
    printf("\n\tWhat is your name?:");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\n\tHi,%s\n",name);
    return 0; /* Add this */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `clang` compiler, getting following warning messages:

```
prg.c:2:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
prg.c:6:12: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[30]' [-Wformat]
scanf("%c",&name);    
       ~~  ^~~~~
prg.c:7:24: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
printf("\n\tHi,%c.n\n",name);    
               ~~      ^~~~
               %s
```

The first warning is for missing `main()` type specifier. In older version of C (C89/90), if the type specifier is missing then it will default set to `int`. Of course, you will get warning message when compile with `C99 & C11` compiler because this implicit declaration is no longer supported.

Second warning message is for incompatible argument for `%c` format specifier. If you want to input a string, you should use format specifier `%s`. But remember that `%s` format specifier matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters. If width specifier is used, matches up to width or until the first whitespace character, whichever appears first. So, if you give input as

```
name surname
```

it will only consume `name` because there is whitespace character after word `name` in the input. Rest of the input will be remain in input buffer.

Instead of using `scanf()`, you should use `fgets()`, like this:

```
if (fgets(name, NAME_LEN, stdin) == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Input error");
    return -1;
}
name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0; // to remove trailing \n from input buffer
```

Read more about `fgets()` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Third warning is for using incompatible format specifier and its corresponding argument in `printf()`. If you want to print a string, you should use `%s` format specifier.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LEN 30

int main(void)
{
    char name[NAME_LEN];    
    printf("\n\tWhat is your name? : ");    
    if (fgets(name, NAME_LEN, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Input error");
        return -1;
    }
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0; // to remove trailing \n from input buffer

    printf("\n\tHi, %s\n",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
scanf("%c", &name);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

since `name` is an array of characters, in other words a string, for which we use the `%s` format specifier. That's why we pass the whole array as a the 2nd parameter of the method, thus we don't use `&` anymore.

The `%c` is used when we want to use exactly one character.

Similarly, you should print with the string format specifier too, like this:

```
printf("\n\tHi,%s.n\n", name);
```

where I do not know if you wish the ".n" to be contained in the output, but it seems that you already know how to use a newline character...

---

### Debug tip

You could easily figure that out by enabling warning flags in your compiler. In GCC for example, I compiled like this:

> gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra

and got:

```
prog.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    2 | main()
      | ^~~~
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:6:9: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[30]' [-Wformat=]
    6 | scanf("%c",&name);
      |        ~^  ~~~~~
      |         |  |
      |         |  char (*)[30]
      |         char *
prog.c:7:17: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
    7 | printf("\n\tHi,%c.n\n",name);
      |                ~^      ~~~~
      |                 |      |
      |                 int    char *
      |                %s
```

where the first warning can go away by declaring the main method as `int main(void)`, and the second & third as we discussed before (by using the `%s`).

<kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5U5T4u7WBtnTzCjN)</kbd>